# Notepad++ replace slashes with spaces between <Tags>1/2/3</Tags> Regex

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++, wildcard, slash

I have 1500+ xml files and need to change the content between a specific set of `<tags></tags>`

**My file currently looks like this (all squished)**

```
<actor>Natalie Portman/Zooey Deschanel/James Franco/Danny McBride</actor>
```

**I want it to look like this (spaced apart)**

```
<actor>Natalie Portman / Zooey Deschanel / James Franco / Danny McBride</actor>
```

**My search and replace efforts below**

```
Find What: `<actor>(.*)/(.*)</actor>`
Replace with: <actor>(\1 \/ \2)</actor>
```

**My result only separates the last slash**

```
<actor>Natalie Portman/Zooey Deschanel/James Franco / Danny McBride</actor>
```

using a global search and replace of all slashes is not suitable as the xml file contain many slashes in the form of tag open/closes, xml declarations and general urls containg slashes;

**see example below:**

```
    <genre>Action</genre>
    <director>David Gordon Green</director>
    <trailer>http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FplWxtPzWY8</trailer>
</details>
```

Comment: You can't do such job with a single regex in a single pass. You'd better write a script that uses an XML parser.

Comment: I was going to say that sounds like it will be a great movie based on the actors... then I looked at the trailer and saw what actual movie it was... what a waste :-)

Answer (score 0):

Possible in **SynWrite** app.

- Make macro which replaces 1 tag content with anything
- Run this macro "until end of file"

To make macro,

- start macro-record
- call Find, regex `<t>.+?<`, opt "from caret"
- call Replace, opt "in selection", from `/` to anything
- stop record
- goto dialog "Macros - Customize macros" and u see this

[image]

here command "Find dialog" in unneeded, delete it from macro, and macro OK.

Comment: Rprogram, your suggestion is closure to working then mine, I have downloaded SynWrite and have managed to get it working with one file that is open in the editor, but unsure how to apply the Macro with "Find/Replace in Files" I don't want open XML files one at a time, apply recorded Macro, save and close.